Импортировать в google таблицу цены на топливо с биржи
Возникла необходимость в расчетах КП использовать актуальные цены с топливной биржи. Готовых решений, к сожалению, не нашел.
Нашел документацию API, но разобраться не смог уже на этапе процедуры авторизации. https://spimex.com/upload/iblock/249/b5vyhycqc3py4a52d4bs8mlxj846qud5.pdf
Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально ли получать от них данные или это только для внутреннего пользования документация?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Не вижу ничего сложного, в документации всё написано, какие параметры передаются в теле, какие  заголовках и т.д. Ответ на вопрос "Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально ли получать от них данные или это только для внутреннего пользования документация?": это вам следует уточнить у технической поддержки, т.к. только они могут ответить на этот вопрос.
